# Using a form how to save to another table with foreign key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a user and extend the data to another table using foreign key.
For example. I have a user and the user has the basic fields name, email, password etc. I am trying to extend the data into another table called user_audience. I can create a users with the basic fields but cant data to save to the user_audience table with a check mark. If a a new user falls into an audience we want to checkmark it and save the value of 1 to the database under that user audience column. Just not sure how to handle data sent to another table Im sure I need some adjustments. Thanks in advance.

[image: user table]
[image: user audience table]

UserController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'company' => 'required',
        'customer_number' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    $user = User::create(request(
        [
            'name', 
            'email', 
            'password', 
            'username', 
            'company', 
            'customer_number'
        ]));


    return redirect()->route('admin.users.index')->with('success','User has been created successfully.');
}
```

UserModel

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use App\Models\UserAudidence;

/**
 * @property Role $role
 */
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'role_id',
        'customer_id',
        'name',
        'username',
        'company',
        'email',
        'password',
        'affected_public',
        'affected_public_mu',
        'affected_public_row',
        'affected_public_mfdu',
        'damage_prevention_demo',
        'damage_prevention',
        'damage_prevention_residential',
        'emergency_official',
        'excavator',
        'first_responder',
        'first_responder_fire',
        'first_responder_police',
        'public_official',
        'public_official_school',
        'school',
        'worker_ag',
        'worker_contractor',
        'worker_contractor_ag',
        'worker_contractor_tree',
        'worker_cranes',
        'worker_crop_duster',
        'worker_farm',
        'worker_fence',
        'worker_fiber',
        'worker_landscaping',
        'worker_overhead',
        'worker_orchard',
        'worker_roofers_overhead',
        'worker_roofers',
        'worker_tree',
        'worker_tree_landscaping',
        'worker_right_tree',
        'worker_loggers',
        'worker_tree_rental_equip',
        'worker_at_risk',
        'worker_cross_bore',
    ];
 /**
     * Add a mutator to ensure hashed passwords
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    // Relationship between User and UserAudience
    public function UserAudidence(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserAudidence::class,);
    }
```

UserAudience Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserAudience extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'affected_public',
        'affected_public_mu',
        'affected_public_row',
        'affected_public_mfdu',
        'damage_prevention_demo',
        'damage_prevention',
        'damage_prevention_residential',
        'emergency_official',
        'excavator',
        'first_responder',
        'first_responder_fire',
        'first_responder_police',
        'public_official',
        'public_official_school',
        'school',
        'worker_ag',
        'worker_contractor',
        'worker_contractor_ag',
        'worker_contractor_tree',
        'worker_cranes',
        'worker_crop_duster',
        'worker_farm',
        'worker_fence',
        'worker_fiber',
        'worker_landscaping',
        'worker_overhead',
        'worker_orchard',
        'worker_roofers_overhead',
        'worker_roofers',
        'worker_tree',
        'worker_tree_landscaping',
        'worker_right_tree',
        'worker_loggers',
        'worker_tree_rental_equip',
        'worker_at_risk',
        'worker_cross_bore',
    ];
}
```

Bladefile

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.users.store') }}" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate" id="kt_create_account_form">
    @csrf

    <label class="required fs-6 fw-semibold mb-2">UserName</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="Username" name="username">   

    <label class="fs-6 fw-semibold mb-2">Email</label>

    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
      
    <label class="required fs-6 fw-semibold mb-2">Password</label>

    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
  
    <label class="form-label required">Company Name</label>
   
    <input name="company_name" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" placeholder="Company Name" value="">

    <label class="form-label required">Customer Number</label>
    
    <input name="customer_number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" placeholder="Customer Number" value="">
  
    <label class="d-flex align-items-center form-label">Phone</label>
   
    <input name="phone" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" value="Phone Number">
  
    <label class="d-flex align-items-center form-label">Address</label>
  
    <input name="address" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" placeholder="Street Address" value="">
   
    <label class="d-flex align-items-center form-label">City</label>
   
    <input name="city" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" placeholder="City" value="">
   
    <label class="d-flex align-items-center form-label">State</label>
    
    <input name="state" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" placeholder="State" value="">

    <label class="d-flex align-items-center form-label">Zipcode</label>
   
    <input name="zipcode" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid" placeholder="Zipcode" value="">
   
    <label class="d-flex align-items-center form-label mb-5">Select Audiences 
                  
    <label class="d-flex flex-stack mb-5 cursor-pointer">Agricultural Worker</span>
                                    
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="true" name="worker_contractor">                                     

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary me-3" data-kt-stepper-action="submit">Submit</button>
       
</form>
```

Create users migrations

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->integer('customer_number');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('company');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->string('zipcode');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('audience_id')->nullable();
           
        });
```

add user audience table migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_audiences', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id'); // by default the primary key is set to unsigned big integer
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); //associate the address with a user
            $table->string('affected_public');
            $table->string('affected_public_mu');
            $table->string('affected_public_row');
            $table->string('affected_public_mfdu');
            $table->string('damage_prevention_demo');
            $table->string('damage_prevention');
            $table->string('damage_prevention_residential');
            $table->string('emergency_official');
            $table->string('excavator');
            $table->string('first_responder');
            $table->string('first_responder_fire');
            $table->string('first_responder_police');
            $table->string('public_official');
            $table->string('public_official_school');
            $table->string('school');
            $table->string('worker_ag');
            $table->string('worker_contractor');
            $table->string('worker_contractor_ag');
            $table->string('worker_contractor_tree');
            $table->string('worker_cranes');
            $table->string('worker_crop_duster');
            $table->string('worker_farm');
            $table->string('worker_fence');
            $table->string('worker_fiber');
            $table->string('worker_landscaping');
            $table->string('worker_overhead');
            $table->string('worker_orchard');
            $table->string('worker_roofers_overhead');
            $table->string('worker_roofers');
            $table->string('worker_tree');
            $table->string('worker_tree_landscaping');
            $table->string('worker_right_tree');
            $table->string('worker_loggers');
            $table->string('worker_tree_rental_equip');
            $table->string('worker_at_risk');
            $table->string('worker_cross_bore');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
```

Comment: you want to insert the same form data in both tables, and giving the `user_id` of the newly created `User` instance. Am i getting this right?

Comment: Not the same data into both tables but some data into the user table the basic info and audience_id this will hold the id for the audience table row id (labeled user_id I see this might be wrong), 
And the user audience checkboxes those be saved to the user audience table.
So when we pull a user we can see which audiences he has by pulling the user and the id associated with it. I hope that makes sense. I just don't want everything in one table.

Comment: i didn't quite understand what are you trying to do, but I'll try to help you anyway. You need to get the `users_audiences.user_id` of `User` id, and `users.audience_id` of `users_audiences` id, right?

Comment: I just need to save everything to the database like my example above. I uploaded to 2 images of my database to my OP. This will show you what I am trying to accomplish when creating a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand. You want to save data in **users** table then in **users_audiences** table.
As per naming conventions it is showing that it has one to many relationship. each user has many user_audiences.

And it you has foregin key constraint on users_audience. Therefore, you cannot add data to users_audiences untill you have coresponding record in users table.

For that you must create users record and save it to DB.

```
$user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->name = $request->input('email');
    //and soo on...
    //then save it...
    $user->save();
```

After that...  create UserAudience object and save it...

```
    $userAudience = new UserAudience();
    $userAudience->user_id = $user->id
//access then above created user ID and store in user_id column...
    $userAudience->school= $request->input('school');
    $userAudience->worker_ag = $request->input('worker_ag');
    //and soo on...
    //then save it...
    $userAudience->save();
```

After that use the above user object to save audience id to it

```
$user->audience_id = $userAudience->id;
$user->save();
```

In this way you have already created user record in DB and it will not give constraint error

Comment: That's what I understood if you means something other than that then elaborate your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `user_id` to the `fillable` array on `UserAudience` model and the same thing for `audience_id` on `User` model.

then you need to create the user first, since `audience_id` is nullable:

```
$user = User::create([

//your basic data here
]);
```

then you create the audience and fill the `user_id` with the previously created id

```
$audience = UserAudience::create([
'user_id' => $user->id,
//the rest of your data
]) ;
```

then updating the `$user` with the associated `audience_id`

```
$user->audience_id = $audience->id;
$user->save() ;
```